# How can I turn multiple categorical data for the forecasting using LSTM model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, lstm, data-preprocessing

Here is a part of my dataset but I am not 100% sure how I am supposed to categorise my dataset. I have been thinking about dummy and one-hot encoding methods for Districts and Crime types and set month as an index but I don't see the pattern for it. My goal is to forecast the total amount of crimes in the city and per district and the total specific crime types in the city and per district. So for instance, the total amount of crimes from 2011-2025 in the city and the total amount of shoplifting in Stoke Bishop in 2011-2025.

```
        Month          Districts                    Crime type
0  2018-01-01       Stoke Bishop  Violence and sexual offences
1  2018-01-01  St Philip's Marsh                   Shoplifting
2  2018-01-01        Barton Hill                         Drugs
3  2018-01-01  St Philip's Marsh                   Shoplifting
4  2018-01-01  St Philip's Marsh                   Shoplifting
```

Answer (score 0):

as you said you can use one-hot-encoding for Regions and Crime types. You can create 3 different variables as a month, year, and day from the Month variable and make the filtering you want over these variables.